# How can I set the sort column, order, and glyph, on a DataGridView column for the initial sort order?

Tags: .net, winforms, datagridview

I have a DataGridView with all columns set to *Automatic* sort mode. When I initially populate the grid, I use the OrderBy LINQ method to set the initial order, e.g. CustomerName, but when the user clicks the CustomerName column header, the grid redundantly sorts first ascending, and only then displays a glyph telling the user about the sort order.

I know I can programmatically sort by a column when I populate the grid, but everything I read indicates the columns' sort modes should then be Programmatic. I want to keep the Automatic sort after the initial sort. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example, to sort by the first column, ascending, you initially do:

```
dataGridView1.Sort(dataGridView1.Columns[0], ListSortDirection.Ascending);
```

The sorting glyph will appear and you keep Automatic mode.